# Why are the following two sets of ciphers "different"?

Tags: cipher-selection

`openssl ciphers -v 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESCGM'` gives:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

whereas `openssl ciphers -v 'DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM'` gives

```
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Indeed, using the former will make SSLLabs not "find" for example the cipher suite "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)". It does however work with the latter, four cipher suites in total are found:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
```

However it seems that in that case the more unsecure ciphers are listed/used first.

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `openssl ciphers -v 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESCGM'` gives:
>   ...
>   whereas `openssl ciphers -v 'DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM'` gives
>   ...

Both cipher lists have `ECDH+AESGCM` in common. But the second cipher list has `DH+AESGCM` whereas the first has `DH+AESCGM` - i.e. GCM vs. CGM.  There are no `DH+AESCGM` ciphers thus the first cipher list only contains `ECDH+AESGCM`.

Comment: Haha damn. It's a typo. Oh man...